# Is there a way to make italic text within italic text non-italic?

Tags: css

Typically, the way to emphasize text within italic text is to make it non-italic. For example:

*The publication of James Joyce's* Ulysses *was met with great controversy.*

I know I can do this:

```
em em { 
  font-style: normal; 
}
```

But that won't work if my parent italicized phrase doesn't use `<em>`. For instance, it won't work if I have

```
<p class="photo-caption">The publication of James Joyce's <em>Ulysses</em> was met with great controversy.</p>
```

Of course, I can do this:

```
.photo-caption em { 
  font-style: normal; 
}
```

but this has potential maintainability problems, since every change to the parent element now also requires a change to the child element.

Is there a way to tell CSS to globally unitalicize nested italics?

Comment: I don't see how...CSS can only style based on a selector. If you don't use a selector to define the italics how can you select something based on a non-selection.

Comment: i know i posted the same thing as you did :P so if i get you right you want an __if__ clause if a parent container has `font-style: italic`?

Answer (score 3):

The capabilities of CSS are necessarily limited so that browsers can process the rules quickly.

I think your original approach is correct, but you can address your concerns about maintainability with a CSS preprocessor, like [LESS](http://lesscss.org). These tools support much more advanced logic while still compiling down to lean and mean CSS.

With LESS, specifically, you could create a rule like this:

```less
@PhotoCaptionFontStyle: italic;

/* Reverses the font style of child EM's if the parent value is italic */
.reverse-em(@parentFontStyle) when (@parentFontStyle = italic){
    EM {
        font-style: normal;
    }
}

.photo-caption {
    font-style: @PhotoCaptionFontStyle;

    /* make child EMs normal if @PhotoCaptionFontStyle is "italic" */
    .reverse-em(@PhotoCaptionFontStyle)
}
```

<sup>(for inspiration. not tested. see [variables](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature) and [guarded mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature))</sup>

If @PhotoCaptionFontStyle is `italic`, then the compiled result would look something like this:

```css
.photo-caption {
    font-style: italic;
}
.photo-caption EM {
    font-style: normal;
}
```

If you switched @PhotoCaptionFontStyle back to `normal`, you'd end up with something like this:

```css
.photo-caption {
    font-style: normal;
}
/* ".photo-caption EM" is never generated
   because of the guard condition */
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is something like this:

```
<p class="photo-caption italic">Lorem <em>ipsum</em></p>

.italic em {font-style: normal;}
```

Comment: I think the concern is that if someone later goes back and makes photo-caption non-italic, then they'd need to also adjust the HTML and other CSS rules. Maintainability is the main issue in the question, not technical know-how.